# Regex: Find all words that starts with `un|unui|o|unei` follow by any words, but after that words have the connecting element `de`

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to find a regex formula, as to find all words that starts with `un|unui|o|unei` follow by any words, but after that words have the connecting element `"de"`

```
unui model de amintire 
un pericol de inundatie
o carte plina de inspiratie
unei casete de sticla
```

**Extracted from the text:**

`Trebuie sa ma dedic unui model de amintire care sa ma faca sa ma simt bun. Trebuie, mai ales, sa evit un pericol de inundatie care poate afecta fizicul. Am citit chiar azi o carte plina de inspiratie care m-a facut sa ma simt erou. Sunt prizonierul unei casete de sticla care nu se va sparge niciodata.`

**The Outcome, only for find, not replace:**

```
model
pericol
carte plina
casete
```

My regex is not so good.

**FIND:** `un|unui|o|unei(.*?)de\x20\w+`

Comment: What is the exact expected outcome? With the regex you presented (if it was correct) it'd just select all lines as a whole. I fail to see the purpose.

Comment: yes, I update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** to match updated requirement of not matching when words are in different (presumably English) sentences:

```
\b(?:un|unui|o|unei)\s+\K[^.?!]+?(?=\s+de\b)
```

The only change is `.+?` -> `[^.?!]+?` which now matches anything except `.`, `!` and `?` in a non greedy way.

The simpliest way to do it is with help of `\K`:

```
\b(?:un|unui|o|unei)\s+\K.+?(?=\s+de\b)
```

Explantation:

- `\b(?:un|unui|o|unei)` - alternative of the beginning of the pattern as a non-capturing group, preceded by word boundary
- `\s+` - any number of whitespace after it
- `\K` - start matching at this position
- `.+?` - anything matched non-greedily
- `(?=\s+de\s+)` - positive lookahead of word `de` preceded by any whitespace and ended with any sort of word boundary

That's if you want to just find the words in the middle. If you want to replace them, it's much simplier with usage of capture groups (other solution that was just added revolves around it).

Comment: almost good. I need only find, not replace. The single problem of your regex is that it finds larger sentences, and I need to find pieces of sentences within those words. So, maybe you can find an alternative regex for your answer, as to find pieces from each sentence, not entire sentences.

Comment: I could, but first you need to edit the question and provide examples of that.

Comment: I edit already, a little bit.

Comment: I don't see any large sentences. We need to know exact requirements like what should make it stop, for instance.

Comment: see now, please

Comment: Where's the case of my regex matching more in that? But ok, let's assume there is e.g. one sentence with `unui` and then another sentence with `de`. How do you exactly interpret sentences? Should just stop matching at `.`, `?`,`!` or something else? There are a lot of possibilities in various languages. I'll edit my answer for that case.

Comment: must matching the words from each sentences, after `. [dot]`

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:un|unui|o|unei)\h+(.+?)\h+de\h+.+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
(?:un|unui|o|unei)  # non capture group, one of these words
\h+                 # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(.+?)               # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\h+                 # 1 or more horizontal spaces
de                  # literally
\h+                 # 1 or more horizontal spaces
.+                  # 1 or more any character but newline
$                   # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: almost good. I need only find, not replace. The single problem of your regex is that it finds larger sentences, and I need to find pieces of sentences within those words. So, maybe you can find an alternative regex for your answer, as to find pieces from each sentence, not entire sentences.

Comment: and, dont use `^` because those words are not at the beginning of lines, only in my example I extracted them from larger sentences